# The QFileDialog from my sandboxed application throws deny file-read-xattr error

Tags: macos, qt, appstore-sandbox

Since I enabled sandbox on my *Qt* application, I have many log message in the console when navigating with the *QFileDialog*:

```
23/02/2016 12:25:51,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: Joker(87965) deny file-read-xattr /Users/martin/Documents/a.txt
23/02/2016 12:25:51,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: Joker(87965) deny file-read-xattr /Users/martin/Documents/b.txt
23/02/2016 12:25:52,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: Joker(87965) deny file-read-xattr /Users/martin/Documents/c.txt
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [here](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/04/03/how-to-publish-qt-applications-in-the-mac-app-store-2/),

> The file save dialog requires a non-empty default filename to work correctly inside a sandbox. You can supply a default filename to the save dialog as follows:

```
QString fileSavePath = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save file", "default filename");
```

> Or if you create the dialog instance yourself:

```
QFileDialog *fileSaveDialog = new QFileDialog(this);
fileSaveDialog->setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptSave);
fileSaveDialog->selectFile("default filename");
```

You should probably also use a custom info.plist and insert the key `ForAppStore`, with a value of `yes`

To build with a custom plist, create the file and reference it in the .pro like this: -

```
QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = Info.plist
```